# ggplot legend title: superscript messes up formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting, legend, superscript

as you can see (see image below), the superscript in my legend title is moved all the way to the right (probably due to the long word in the first line). First I assumed changing the line height of the title would help, but it didn't. Also I want to have have the line break in order to save space.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

```
library("ggplot2")
x <- seq(1,10,1)
y <- sin(x)
z <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", "3", "3")

df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=z))
p + geom_point() +
  labs(
    color = expression(
      paste(
        "Catalyst Loading \n(mg cm"^{-2}*")"
        )
      )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `\n` that messes you legend title. To work with line breaks and expressions I would suggest `atop` solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
nameColor <- bquote(atop(Catalyst~Loading~phantom(),
                         (mg~cm^-2)))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
    geom_point() +
    labs(color = nameColor)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Is there a way to align the entire legend title left? So the unit isn't centred?

Comment: @MineralwaterJo How about `theme(legend.position = "bottom")` and just remove the line break? It would also look good.

Comment: You're right, it looks good but since I'm going to arrange multiple plots in a grid (one column), I'd prefer to put the legend to the left. I think I'll go with your first proposal, the centred title looks good too.