# Wrap legend title that has superscripts

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I wrap a `ggplot()` legend title that has superscripts? In the example below I would like to wrap the legend titles after the word 'Temperature'

Example Data (trying `\n`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, fill = hp, size = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                       midpoint = mean(mtcars$hp),
                       name = 'Air Temperature \nTrend (<sup>o</sup>C yr<sup>-1</sup>)') +
  scale_size_continuous(name = 'Air Temperature \nTrend (<sup>o</sup>C yr<sup>-1</sup>)') +
  theme(legend.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

There was a similar SO question ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953704/ggplot-legend-title-superscript-messes-up-formatting)) that did not work for me in this example.

```
nameFill <- bquote(atop(Air~Temperature~phantom(),
                         Trend~(degree*C~yr^-1)))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, fill = hp, size = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red",
                       midpoint = mean(mtcars$hp),
                       name = nameFill) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = nameFill) +
  theme(legend.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ggtext` you have to use a `<br>` tag instead of `\n` to add a linebreak:

```r
library(ggtext)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, fill = hp, size = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    midpoint = mean(mtcars$hp),
    name = "Air Temperature<br>Trend (<sup>o</sup>C yr<sup>-1</sup>)"
  ) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Air Temperature<br>Trend (<sup>o</sup>C yr<sup>-1</sup>)") +
  theme(legend.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

And when going the `atop` approach you have to drop `element_markdown`:

```r
nameFill <- bquote(
  atop(
    Air ~ Temperature,
    Trend ~ (degree * C ~ yr^-1)
  )
)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = hp, fill = hp, size = mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(
    low = "blue", high = "red",
    midpoint = mean(mtcars$hp),
    name = nameFill
  ) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = nameFill)
```

[image]